# How to assign a new tag on existing SQL Server using Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

In [docs for Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/tag?view=azure-cli-latest#az-tag-create-examples) I can see how to create a tag on my resource. It works as supposed to. However, it's clunky to specify the ID, so I wonder if there's a way to add tag to a resource only knowing its name.

Naturally, I could do the following.

```
$SqlServerId = az sql server show `
                 --resource-group ressy-grouppie `
                 --name sql-servy-v12 `
                 --query "id"
az tag create --resource-id $SqlServerId --tags monkey=donkey
```

But I can't help if there's a shorter way, without actually creating the intermediate value holding the ID. It seems like the general philosophy of the Azure CLI is to refer to things by their names not only IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like the general philosophy of the Azure CLI is to refer to things by their names not only IDs.

Unfortunately, You cannot create a tag on a resource in Azure Services by just using its name, The functionality of creating a tag command requires the resource id of the resource and not just the name.

Resource id for Sql server is :

```
/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/yyy/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/zzz
```

Here `xxx` is subscription id
`yyy` is name of the resource group
`zzz` is name of the server

So id not so different.

And currently as of today, the only way of doing this is the way  you have done:

[image]

[image]